# Strange behavior of counters in review queues

Tags: bug, status-completed, review

As it seems currently there is an issue with the review queues that the counter for the number of accomplished reviews does not updates immediately $-$ as it used to be $-$ but only when refreshing or reopening the page. I have only noticed this behavior in case of the close votes, the suggested edits and late answers; from here it might be deducible that this is a general problem. I have checked it on another device and the same happend.

A quick search on the main stackexchange meta website does not yield any information regarding the issue or any related post within the past $24$ hours. But honestly speaking, I do not know exactly what I am looking for.

> Is anyone else experiencing something similiar or is it just me? Does anybody know anything about earlier related issues?

---

**EDIT:** The issue seem to be resolved as hinted in the linked threads.

Comment: I notices the same thing in the first post reviews.

Comment: [meta.se]: [Why is the updated All Time review counter not updated anymore while performing reviews?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343728) (Found [by José Carlos Santos](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/20352?m=53550348#53550348).)

Comment: Rather than closing as "no longer relevant", there is a "status resolved" tag (available only to moderators) that is customarily applied to bugs once they are confirmed to be fixed.

Comment: @hardmath I wasn't aware of this feature. Shall I mark my post as in need of moderator intervention then?

Comment: Sure, that will work.